# Notify multiple waiters one by one

Tags: java, multithreading, notifications

I started dealing with Thread's notify() and wait(), I know that can be done easily by adding all waiters to a Queue for example, but still I wonder if theres any way to do it without a Queue, to have multiple waiters and notify generally each time one by one (without any order).

Comment: "to have multiple waiters and notify generally each time one by one"... That's exactly what `wait()` and `notify()` does. If 3 threads call `wait()` on the same object and a `notify()` is called on that object afterwards, one of the threads (randomly chosen) is woken up!

Comment: @ParkerHalo, you should say, "unspecified" rather than "random".  The Javadoc for `o.notify()` says, "The choice is arbitrary and occurs at the discretion of the implementation."  "Random" implies a particular behavior, that the Javadoc does not require.

Answer (score 1):

The alternatives are:

- Notify all threads waiting on the object at the same time using `obj.notifyAll()`.
- Notify one of the waiting threads using `obj.notify()`.

There is no way to notify a specific thread.

I guess that you could use the length of a `Queue` as a hint as to the number of times to call `obj.notify()`, but my recommendation is "don't".  There are all sorts of potential hazards in that approach.

---

You've not told us what concurrency problem you are trying to solve here, but I would recommend that you look for an alternative approach; e.g. using one of the other (higher level) synchronization mechanisms provided by the standard concurrency packages.